# Play - inlining compiled LESS in scala template

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-template

I'm building a scala template which will be used to generate HTML for emails sent from a website.

I'd like it to reuse the same LESS stylesheet I'm using on my website. For this, I'll need the compiled CSS to be available so I can inline it in the output of the scala template (within `<style>` tags, as opposed to CSS in a separate file/URL).

What's the most elegant way of doing this in the Play Framework, please?

Answer (score 0):

i assume you can just include it using the `link` tag..and then use the reverse router like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

it will automatically compile the less file
PS-include this in the html tag

Comment: Thanks, but I'm interested in inlining the CSS, not linking to it as a file or URL - this is for emails, and there are specific requirements I'm looking for to ensure the email is visible in all mail clients.

Comment: okay..a LESS source file at app/assets/stylesheets/main.less will be available as a standard resource at public/stylesheets/main.css so you have the compiled source available but i don't know where to go from here :O